# double parentheses around function parameter list

Tags: c++

I have the following code, it compiles with gcc 4.4 with no warnings, and returns 42.

```
template<typename T>
struct foo
{ };

template<typename T>
struct foo<void (T)>
{
  enum { value = 42 };
};

int main()
{
  return foo<void ((int))>::value;
}
```

Now, I see why it should work when the template parameter is `void (int)`, but what's the deal with the double parentheses? Is this legal in C++? Is it the same as `void (int)`?

Cheers

Comment: I'm obviously missing something... honk and another user feel it's necessary to point out that C++ is not Python - but why? This code seems perfectly un-Python-ish to me.

Comment: @delnan in Python the extra parentheses have a specific meaning, but in C++ they don't. A joke isn't funny anymore when it needs to be explained.

Comment: @Mark: A joke isn't funny either if it's based on misinformation. Don't you people know any Python? Now, `(expr,)` would be a singleton tuple, but `(expr)` is just `expr`. Simply wrapping something in parens doesn't change anything about it in Python, as in every sane language.

Comment: @Mark, @delnan, you are right, late afternoon brainfart.

Comment: If the second struct foo is a specialization, then shouldn't the template line be `template <>`?

Comment: @Adrian: it's a partial specialisation, for function types. It's still parametrised by the function's argument type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, `void ((int))` is identical to `void (int)`.
`void ((int))` part in `foo<void ((int))>` is called `type-id`.
According to §8.1/1, `type-id` is composed of
`type-specifier-seq` and `abstract-declarator`.
In `void ((int))`, `type-specifier-seq` is `void` and `abstract-declarator`
is `((int))`,
and `abstract-declarator` can be parenthesized arbitrarily.
This is legal in C and C++.

Comment: This is the answer.  `void ((int))` is a funny *type-id* meaning the type `g` is declared to have in funny declaration `void (g(int))`, which has the same meaning as the more usual declaration `void g(int)`.

Answer (score 3):

The inner parentheses are used to change the order of evaluation of the expression. Order doesn't matter when there's only a single part to the expression, so they're effectively doing nothing.

Comment: If this is legal, why does g++ reject `void f((int)) {}`?  I suspect the original example is invalid syntax and the fact it's accepted is a compiler bug.

Comment: That's true, but does it apply here?  Redundant parens don't matter in an expression, but this is a type specification.

Comment: @Adrian, a type expression is an expression too. Parentheses don't matter in this case, but there are plenty of examples where they do.

Comment: @aschepler, I think your example is one of the cases I alluded to above. By telling the compiler to start the expression evaluation at the `int`, it no longer looks like a function specification.

Comment: Okay, but still, there are no expressions or evaluations involved here.

Answer (score 1):

- Templates are unlike macros.
- Your "void (T)" is same as "void T" and "void ((int))" is same as "void int" just like "void ((((int))))" is same as "void int". <strike>The expression in parentheses is evaluated as @Mark pointed out.</strike>

Comment: There is no expression involved, and nothing is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it's *not* needed for this purpose, but the main reason for double parens like this, is to avoid the most vexing parse.

The double parens aren't allowed in a function declaration, but are in a function call, so code that would otherwise produce the most vexing parse can be forced to be a function call by enclosing at least one argument in double parentheses.

Some of the code I included in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162108/a-better-way-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-of-strings-in-c-c-using-whitespace/3162187#3162187) demonstrated this.