# Write CSV file into vectors

Tags: c++

I have 8x14800 matrix that has been  extracted from matlab as CSV file ("moves.mo").
I need to read this file into 14800 vectors with 8 values each. Can you please navigate me here?

So far, I am here:

```
std::fstream inputfile;
inputfile.open("moves.mo");
std::vector< std::vector<int>* >  vectorsmovesList; 

while (!inputfile.eof()) {
    std::string line;             
    getline (inputfile,line);
    if(""!=line) {        //if line is nonempty

       std::vector<int>* mvec = new std::vector<int>(); //allocate a vector vec(N)
 /* loop to read file has to go here */     
           }
inputfile.close();

}

return 0;
}
```

Thank you very very much!!!!

Comment: Maybe not an exact duplicate, but see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894886/parsing-a-comma-delimited-stdstring/1895584

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string)