# parsing string with respect to string format |how

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I have ;

```
 string  str = "";
```

in str, I store data is in following form "_ : _, _ "
"_" can be just a word like "X" or a composition of words like "a sds 23 dsds 1"

I want them parse it to three different string ;

```
in str       : X:y dfj kd kk,sdd 12 89 ++
string parsed[i] ;
in parsed[0] : X
in parsed[1] : y dfj kd kk
in parsed[2] : sdd 12 89 ++
```

**How** can I do that over using c++ std::string features ?

Comment: What is the string format?  What is the rule to break up `str`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing a comma-delimited std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894886/parsing-a-comma-delimited-stdstring)

Comment: or this: [how do I tokenize a string in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your string using the following std:string methods for example:

```
size_t index1 = str.find( ":" ) + 1;
size_t index2 = str.find( ",", index1 ) + 1;

std::string sub1 = str.substr (0, index1-1);
std::string sub2 = str.substr (index1, index2-index1-1);
std::string sub3 = str.substr (index2, str.length()-index2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `boost/algorithm/string.hpp`

```
std::string str = "X:y dfj kd kk,sdd 12 89 ++"
std::vector<std::string> v;
boost::split(v, str, boost::is_any_of(":,"));
```

You can also use it for multibyte strings.