# Assigning Comma Delimited Data to Vector

Tags: c++, file, vector, delimiter

I have some comma delimited data in a file, like so:

```
116,88,0,44
66,45,11,33
```

etc. I know the size, and I want each line to be its own object in the vector.

Here is my implementation:

```
bool addObjects(string fileName) {
   
   ifstream inputFile;
   
   inputFile.open(fileName.c_str());
   
   string fileLine;
   stringstream stream1;
   int element = 0;
   
   if (!inputFile.is_open()) {
       return false;
   }
   
   while(inputFile) {
           getline(inputFile, fileLine); //Get the line from the file
           MovingObj(fileLine); //Use an external class to parse the data by comma
           stream1 << fileLine; //Assign the string to a stringstream
           stream1 >> element; //Turn the string into an object for the vector
           movingObjects.push_back(element); //Add the object to the vector
       }
   
   inputFile.close();
   return true;
}
```

No luck so far. I get errors in the

```
stream1 << fileLine
```

and the push_back statement. The stream1 one tells me there's no match for the << operator (there should be; I included the library) and the latter tells me movingObjects is undeclared, seemingly thinking that it is a function, when it is defined in the header as my vector.

Can anyone offer any assistance here?

Comment: `std::vector<int> movingObjects();` is a function declaration if that's what you wrote. To call the default constructor, `std::vector<int> movingObjects{};` works, but so does `std::vector<int> movingObjects;`. No form of brackets/braces needed for it.

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "vector file".  There are too many of those related questions so far.

Comment: Also, put the `getline` into the loop condition so it doesn't use a failed read.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing a comma-delimited std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894886/parsing-a-comma-delimited-stdstring)

Comment: I did search, I didn't find anything helpful to my specific case unfortunately. The comma delimited data is rather tricky.

I should've clarified that the vector objects have a few attributes, but they are all ints, as per my data file example. 

Fixed a few minor issues, still having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your intentions this should be close to what you're trying to do:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

void MovingObj(std::string & fileLine) {
    replace(fileLine.begin(), fileLine.end(), ',', ' ');
}

bool addObjects(std::string fileName, std::vector<int> & movingObjects) {
    std::ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open(fileName);

    std::string fileLine;
    int element = 0;
    if (!inputFile.is_open()) {
        return false;
    }
    while (getline(inputFile, fileLine)) {
        MovingObj(fileLine); //Use an external class to parse the data by comma
        std::stringstream stream1(fileLine); //Assign the string to a stringstream
        while ( stream1 >> element ) {
            movingObjects.push_back(element); //Add the object to the vector
        }
    }
    inputFile.close();
    return true;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> movingObjects;
    std::string fileName = "data.txt";
    addObjects(fileName, movingObjects);
    for ( int i : movingObjects ) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: [#NoRawLoops](https://godbolt.org/z/PGvxEz1Kr) (may require time travel)