# Read file line by line and store values

Tags: c++, file

I have a file.txt like:

```
4,3
3,2
5,1
6,5
```

Every line is a coordinate. For the first line, x1=4, y1 = 3. Then for the second line, x2=3, y2=2, and so on. The purpose of this method is to get the 4 coordinates inside the file and store them inside a variables or an array. I thought the best way was to create an array for x and another one for y, so we would have `coordX[]` and `coordY[]`. Since the file I must read will always contain only 4 coordinates, both arrays will have a size of [3].
The code I'm using right now is this:

```
void readFile(){
   int x1, y1;
   int coordX[3], coordY[3];
   while (infile >> x1 >> y1){
       //How to insert the coordinates into coordX[] and coordY[]?
   }
}
```

As you can see, I don't know how to make the method insert the values of each coordinate into the array, is there a way to do it using an array? Or should I create `int` variables x1, y1, x2, y2, and so on? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a Comma Separated Values file.  Please search "stackoverflow c++ read csv".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of coordinates is fixed at four, you could unroll the loop by repeating the read four times, like this:

```
void readFile(){
   int coordX[4], coordY[4];
   infile >> coordX[0] >> coordY[0];
   infile >> coordX[1] >> coordY[1];
   infile >> coordX[2] >> coordY[2];
   infile >> coordX[3] >> coordY[3];
   ...
}
```

You could do it with a loop, too:

```
void readFile(){
   int coordX[4], coordY[4];
   for (int i = 0 ; i != 4 ; i++) {
       infile >> coordX[i] >> coordY[i];
   }
   ...
}
```

Note that since you are reading four items, `coordX` and `coordY` must be declared with four, not three, elements. The general rule is that when you declare an array of `N` items, the valid indexes are from zero, inclusive, to `N-1`, inclusive.

Also note that `coordX` and `coordY` must be either used inside the same function, or copied to a container or a dynamically allocated array in order to be returned from the `readFile` function.

Finally, if the number of items to read is *not* fixed, you should change the code to use a `vector` or a `list` instead of an array, to hold a variable number of results.

> I was just wondering, how do I insert the comma as a token separator?

You can add a peek-and-ignore code similar to what is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894955/335858):

```
void readFile(){
   int coordX[4], coordY[4];
   for (int i = 0 ; i != 4 ; i++) {
       infile >> coordX[i];
       if (infile.peek() == ',') {
           // If the next character is a comma, skip it
           infile.ignore();
       }
       infile >> coordY[i];
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution!! I was just wondering, how do I insert the comma as a token separator? Cause the code works only if the coordinates inside the file are not separated by a comma, let's say: 
`4 2`  
But it won't work if there are commas between the values:
`4, 3`
`4, 2`
Is there a way to do this? Thanks! :)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Your solution is soooo much simple than those posts about reading CSV, thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

With minimal mods to yr original code

```
void readFile(){
   int x, y;
   int i = 0;
   int coordX[4], coordY[4];
   while (infile >> x >> y){
       //How to insert the coordinates into coordX[] and coordY[]?
       coordx[i] = x;
       coordy[i] = y;
       i++;
   }
}
```

of course this code is totally wrong. If the file contains 5 lines it will break, if it contains 3 lines you wont know that the last line was missing. You should be using std::vector,...