# Read an array from standard input, ignoring brackets and commas

Tags: c++, cin

The sample input to my code is:

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

I wish to ignore the curly brackets and commas, and read the numbers into an array.

How can I do that?

Comment: Perhaps by searching the web for examples of "c++ read comma separated values".

Comment: I'd start from [a previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1895584/179910) and add a couple of lines to the `csv_reader` facet to get it to treat `{` and `}` as white-space (just like it currently does for comma, space and new-line.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, this might work:

```
// Ignore all characters up to and including the open curly bracket
cin.ignore(100000, '{');

// Read the numbers into an array
int my_array[4];
unsigned int array_index = 0;
cin >> my_array[array_index];
array_index++;
cin >> my_array[array_index];
array_index++;
cin >> my_array[array_index];
array_index++;
cin >> my_array[array_index];

// Ignore all characters up to and including the newline.
cin.ignore(1000000, '\n');
```

You could use a `for` loop to read in the numbers.

Comment: you're oging to have to put something in to deal with the commas

Answer (score 2):

### Using Regex

An easy fix is to use C++11 *regular expressions* to simply replace all unwanted characters with whitespace and then tokenize the integers using streams as usual.

Let's say you've read the input into a string called `s`, e.g.

```
std::getline(std::cin, s);
```

Then you can simply read all the integers into a `std::vector` using these two lines:

```
std::istringstream ss{std::regex_replace(s, std::regex{R"(\{|\}|,)"}, " ")};
std::vector<int> v{std::istream_iterator<int>{ss}, std::istream_iterator<int>{}};
```

<kbd>[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18564260ad4128f5)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> nums;
    for_each(istream_iterator<string>{cin}, istream_iterator<string>{}, [&](string s) {
        s.erase(remove_if(begin(s), end(s), [](char c) { return !isdigit(c); }), end(s));
        if (!s.empty())
            nums.push_back(stoi(s));
    });
    copy(begin(nums), end(nums), ostream_iterator<int>{cout, ", "});
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Read an array from standard input, ignoring brackets and commas into a vector.

```
#include <algorithm>    // std::replace_if()
#include <iterator>     // std::istream_iterator<>()
#include <sstream>      // std::stringstream
#include <vector>       // std::vector

std::getline(std::cin, line); // { 1, 2, 3, 4 }

std::replace_if(line.begin(), line.end(),
                [](const char& c) { return ((c == '{') || (c == ',') || (c == '}')); },
                ' ');

std::stringstream ss(line); // 1 2 3 4

std::vector<int> v((std::istream_iterator<int>(ss)),
                    std::istream_iterator<int>());
```