# Read from file line by line and parse to vector a lot of ints in c++

Tags: c++, file, parsing, vector

I have seen a lot of similar posts regarding very similar cases but my case is a bit different. I'm a newbie to c++, so any help would be appreciated.

I have a large file full of lines full of integers. Each number is separated by blank spaces. I need diferent lines to stay seperate, i don't want to read all the file on one go. I want to read line by line and parse each line in to a vector of integers. The code I've got is this:

```
int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("numbers.txt");
  vector<int> vec1;
  int const2=0;
  int a;
  while ( getline (myfile,line) ){ // I understand that this reads line 
                                   // by line and stores the string to "line"
    while (line >> a){  // this part is the one i can't get right, i 
                        // want to push_back every int from
                        // the string to vec1 but doesn't work
      vec1.push_back(a); 
      // More stuff
    }
    // more stuff
  }
  myfile.close();   
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What part are you having issues with: reading the file?  creating vectors of vectors? inserting into a vector?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It's probably the part in the code that says "This is the part I can't get right"

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/convert-string-to-int-c)
but there is a lot of different ways, and you even dont need to read line. if in file is only ints you can do something like
 `while(myfile >> a) {
     vec1.push_back(a);
 }`

Comment: If you just want one vector with all the data you only need `while (myfile >> a)...`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing a comma-delimited std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894886/parsing-a-comma-delimited-stdstring)

Comment: Like ThomaMatthews said I have probles where it says so, and I need all the integers from every line in diferent vectors/arrays so reading each number at a time doesn't work for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the C++11 way (use `-std=c++0x` with g++ or clang++), you can google each function that you don't know.
Using `back_inserter` and `istream_iterator` is much cleaner than any while/for loop you would come up with on your own. Using `deque` in this context is also more efficient. Obviously you can also take the file name from the main input.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <deque>

int main()
{
    const std::string filename = "/path/to/file.txt";

    std::string    line_buf;
    std::ifstream  file( filename );

    std::deque< std::deque<int> > parsed_data;
    if (file) while ( std::getline(file,line_buf) )
    {
        std::deque<int>    parsed_line;
        std::stringstream  ss( line_buf );

        std::copy( std::istream_iterator<int>(ss), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(parsed_line) );

        parsed_data.emplace_back();
        parsed_data.back().swap( parsed_line );
    }
}
```

To check the result in your console, you can use this function

```
#include <cstdio>
void show_result( const std::deque< std::deque<int> >& data )
{
    size_t line_count = 0;
    for ( auto& line: data )
    {
        printf( "Line %02ld: ", ++line_count );
        for ( auto& num: line )
            printf( "%d ", num );
            printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream):

```
std::istringstream iss(line);
while(iss >> a) {
     vec1.push_back(a);
     // ....
}
```

But in fact if you only have numbers in that file, it would be enough to leave out the `while ( getline (myfile,line) ){` loop completely and just write

```
while(myfile >> a) {
     vec1.push_back(a);
     // ....
}
```

Comment: The last part doesn't work because I need the numbers of every line in different vectors/arrays.

Comment: @MikeCC So well, you didn't state this in your question. Anyway the `std::istringstream` solution does what you want.

Comment: I did, ". I want to read line by line and parse each line in to a vector of integers." That was on the original post.

Comment: And yes, it does, when I tried to up vote your first comment i was in the first 5 min window and it didn't let me ;)