# How to convert comma separated char* to uint32_t[] array in C

Tags: c, string, casting, char, uint32-t

I want to convert a comma separated char* to an uint32_array[] in C. Is there an easy method/routine to do that?

I already spend a lot of time on SO and found many solutions on C++, but not an C like that :
[Parsing a comma-delimited std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894886/parsing-a-comma-delimited-stdstring)
But I think it is not a good solution to cast from char* to string to string stream to vector and work with the vector.

```
char input[] = "1 , 2 , 34, 12, 46, 100";
```

to

```
uint32_t output[] = { 1 , 2 , 34, 12, 46, 100 };
```

I would appreciate any kind of help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You cannot do this by *casting*. This problem requires *parsing*, i.e. reading the data into an intermediate form and then building a new object with the desired output structure.

Comment: Suggest 2 passes on `input`: Find number count, then 2nd to save the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive algorithm that only makes a single pass. It allocates at the deepest level and fills in on the way out:

```
int *cvt(char *input, int *level)
{
    char *cp = strtok(input, ", ");
    if (cp == NULL) {
        /* No more separators */
        return (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * *level);
    }

    int my_index = -1;
    int n;
    if (sscanf(cp, "%d", &n) == 1) {
        my_index = *level;
        *level += 1;
    } else {
        printf("Invalid integer token '%s'\n", cp);
    }
    int *array = cvt(NULL, level);
    if (my_index >= 0) {
        array[my_index] = n;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Call with:

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    char input[] = "1, 2, bogus, 4, 8, 22, 33, 55";
    int n_array = 0;
    int *array = cvt(input, &n_array);

    int i;
    printf("Got %d members:\n", n_array);
    for (i = 0; i < n_array; ++i)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor: Does not detect lack of comma with `"1  2"`, but then OP did not require that.  Like the using the stack for the temporary place to save the scanned `n`.

Comment: yeah. Also, arguably, you'd want to just return NULL rather than malloc'ing zero bytes if `*level` is zero.

Answer (score 1):

One method (of many):

```
int converted = 0 ;
char* tok = input ;
int i = 0 ;
do
{
    converted = sscanf( tok, "%d", &output[i] ) ;
    tok = strchr( tok, ',' ) + 1 ;
    i++ ;

} while( tok != NULL && converted != 0 ) ;
```

You could use `strtok()` instead of `sscanf()` and `strchr()`, but that *modifies* `input` which may be undesirable.

If the input is a stream rather than a string, then it is simpler:

```
int converted = 0 ;
int i = 0 ;
do
{
    converted = fscanf( fd, "%d,", &output[i] ) ;
    i++ ;

} while( !feof( fd ) && converted != 0 ) ;
```

I have not included any means to prevent `output[i]` from exceeding the bounds - you may need to consider that too.

Comment: it was a bad comment which I deleted within seconds!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int* values;
    int  count;
}
output_t;

output_t Read(char input[])
{
    int*  values = NULL;
    int   count  = 0;
    char* pch    = strtok(input,", ");

    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        values = realloc(values,(count+1)*sizeof(*values));
        values[count++] = atoi(pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL,", ");
    }

    return (output_t){values,count};
}
```

And here is a usage example:

```
void Example()
{
    char input[] = "1 , 2 , 34, 12, 46, 100";
    output_t output = Read(input);
    for (int i=0; i<output.count; i++)
        printf("%d\n",output.values[i]);
    free(output.values);
}
```

Comment: Nice usage of returning a `struct`.  Minor: Like other posts, does not detect `"1 2"` as a problem.

Comment: @chux: I don't think it detects `"ab, 5, cd"` as a problem either, but it doesn't look like that's the primary task at hand. OP can iterate the input string beforehand in order to make sure that it's legal. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw my hat into the ring and do a single pass of the data. I estimate the required array size to be the worst case where every data is of the form "n," so two bytes per number, and resize it afterwards.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned int uint32_t;

int main (void) {
    char input[] = "1 , 2 , 34, 12, 46, 100";
    uint32_t *output, *temp;
    char *tok;
    int elements = 0;
    int len = 1 + strlen(input) / 2;            // estimate max num of elements
    output = malloc(len * sizeof(*output));
    if (output == NULL)
        exit(-1);                               // memory alloc error

    tok = strtok(input, ", ");                  // parse the string
    while (tok != NULL) {
        if (elements >= len)
            exit(-2);                           // error in length assumption
        if (1 != sscanf(tok, "%u", output + elements))
            exit(-3);                           // error in string format
        elements++;
        tok = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    }

    temp = realloc(output, elements * sizeof(*output)); // resize the array
    if (temp == NULL)
        exit(-4);                               // error in reallocating memory
    output = temp;

    for (len=0; len<elements; len++)
        printf("%u ", output[len]);
    printf("\n");
    free(output);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
1 2 34 12 46 100
```

Comment: Minor: Suggest either `unsigned *output` or `printf("%" PRIu32u " ", output[len]);`  2) Does not detect "1 2" as a problem - but then OP said nothing about that.  Like the estimated size though

Comment: @chux it solves "1 2" without commas perfectly well with `strtok(input, ", ")` as posted.

Comment: I'd expect `"1 2"` to be declared a problem as it lacks a delimiting  comma rather than print "1 2".  IAC OP is not clear on that - so to each his own.

Answer (score 0):

Read through the string once to figure out how to size your array:

```
uint32_t n = 1;
for (uint32_t idx = 0; idx < strlen(input); idx++) {
    if (input[idx] == ',') {
        n++;
    }
}
```

There's a different way to do this that doesn't require reading through the string, but it requires resizing the destination array as new elements come in, which makes the code more complex. It's easy enough to read through the string once for small strings.

Make your destination array:

```
uint32_t* output = NULL;
output = malloc(sizeof(*output) * n);
if (!output) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not allocate space for output array!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Populate your array. One way to do this without clobbering the string is to keep a couple pointers to the start and end of a substring that contains the desired numeric element in the comma-separated string, and just loop over all the characters in the string:

```
#define MAX_LEN 13
char* start = &input[0];
char* end = &input[0];
char entry[MAX_LEN];
uint32_t entry_idx = 0;
int finished = 0; // false
do {
    end = strchr(start, ',');
    if (!end) {
        end = input + strlen(input);
        finished = 1;
    }
    memcpy(entry, start, end - start);
    entry[end - start] = '\0';
    sscanf(entry, "%u", &output[entry_idx++]);
    start = end + 1;
} while (!finished);
```

`MAX_LEN` is 13 because it is unlikely that a `uint32_t` will be longer than 13 digits. You can make this longer to future-proof this for computers made in the year 2100.

Be sure to free the array when you're done with it:

```
free(output); 
output = NULL;
```

Comment: You are assuming that the number of values (or some reasonable maximum) is not known *a priori* which may be the case but the explanation of how to deal with it is possibly more than was asked for.

Comment: Fair enough. Lots of ways to skin the cat, I guess.

Comment: Note: As OP has various amount of space between numbers, the number of spaces and digits could well exceed 13 which `entry[end - start]` depends.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int getsize(char* str, char* delimiters) //give the size of the final uint32_t array[]
{
  int count = 0;
  char* st = strdup(str), *t = strtok(st, delimiters);
  while(t)
  {
    count++;
    t = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
  }
  free(st);
  return count;
}

uint32_t* Char_to_Array(char *data, char* delimiters, int *siz) //siz is a pointer to get the size of the array
{
  char* st = strdup(data), *t = NULL; //dup string, strtok mage change on the passed string
  *siz = getsize(data, delimiters);
  uint32_t* buf=(uint32_t *)malloc((*siz)*4);
  t = strtok(st, delimiters); //split string by " "
  int i = 0;
  while(t)
  {
    buf[i] = atoi(t);
    t = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
    i++;
  }
  free(st);
  return buf;
}
```

here a test with a main function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
  int getsize(char* str, char* delimiters), siz = 0, i = 0;
  uint32_t* Char_to_Array(char *data, char* delimiters, int *x);
  uint32_t* t = Char_to_Array("123, 156, 4658,7878", " ,", &siz);
  while(i<siz)
  {
    printf("array[%d] = %d\n", i, t[i]);
    i++;
  }
  free(t);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 pass approach:

1) Count the number of commas and allocate an array.

2) Parse the string - look for errors.

[Late to the uint32 comma party]

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct {
  uint32_t *u32;
  size_t count;
  bool error;
} CSV_32_T;

CSV_32_T CSV_to_int32_list(const char *csv) {
  CSV_32_T list = { NULL, 1, false };

  // 1st pass: Quickly go through list counting commas
  const char *p = csv;
  for (p = csv; *p; p++) {
    if (*p == ',') {
      list.count++;
    }
  }
  size_t i = 0;
  list.u32 = malloc(list.count * sizeof *list.u32);
  if (list.u32) {

    // 2nd pass: scan
    p = csv;
    for (i = 0; i < list.count; i++) {
      if (i > 0 && *p++ != ',') {
        break;
      }
      int n = 0;
      if (1 != sscanf(p, "%" SCNu32 " %n", &list.u32[i], &n)) {
        break;
      }
      p += n;
    }
  }
  if (i != list.count || *p) {
    free(list.u32);
    return (CSV_32_T ) { NULL, 0, true } ;
  }
  return list;
}

void testCSV(const char *csv) {
  CSV_32_T y = CSV_to_int32_list(csv);
  printf("%d %zu \"%s\"\n", y.error, y.count, csv);
}

int main(void) {
  testCSV("1 , 2 , 34, 12, 46, 100");
  testCSV("1  2 , 34, 12, 46, 100");
  return 0;
}
```