# istream_iterator deal with string with pipe

Tags: c++, iterator, istream

I have the following source working fine :

```
int main() {
    string s = "This is a book not a look " ;
    vector<string> svec;
    stringstream ss(s);
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(ss), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(svec));
    for( auto it = svec.begin() ; it != svec.end() ; it++ ){
        cout << "(" << *it << ")" << endl ;
    }
} //main
```

Suppose I use "|" , not space in this sample , what should I modify so that it output the same result ?!  I mean string s = "This|is|a|book|not|a|look" ;

Comment: Replace every space with a pipe? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1894886/395718), especially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1895584/395718).