# error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::vector<int>>::push_back(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)’

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, stdvector, function-call

I am trying to debug this code from my supervisor and I'm new to C++.

I found a few similar **`no matching function for call to`** questions, which gave me ideas what the problem might be but was not able to solve it.

I have listed my thoughts below the error message and relevant function.

**Error message:**

```
In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
distanceMatrixToSageGraph.c:104:43: error: no matching function for call to 
‘std::vector<std::vector<int>>::push_back(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)’     
the_entries.push_back( row_as_vector );
```

**Relevant function:**

```
int main(int argc, char** threshold_and_distanceMatrixfilename)
{
    if (argc < 2 || argc > 2) 
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: ./distanceMatrixToSageGraph.o <threshold> 

            <distanceMatrix_file_calculated_fromDGEsingleCell_data>" << std::endl;
            return -1;
    }
    string distanceMatrixfilename = threshold_and_distanceMatrixfilename[2];
    int threshold = std::stoi(threshold_and_distanceMatrixfilename[1]);
    std::ifstream distanceMatrixFile(distanceMatrixfilename);

    if (!distanceMatrixFile)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error opening distanceMatrix file: " << distanceMatrixfilename << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    string row;
    std::getline(distanceMatrixFile, row); // discard the first row, which specifies the format of the file.
    vector<vector<int>> the_entries;

    while (std::getline(distanceMatrixFile, row))
    {
        std::stringstream row_as_stringstream(row);
        int i; i = 0;
        vector<string> row_as_vector;

        while (row_as_stringstream.good())
        {
            string substr;
            getline(row_as_stringstream, substr, ',');
            row_as_vector.push_back(substr);
        };
        the_entries.push_back(row_as_vector); //LINE 104
    };
}
```

**Ideas:**

- It would be great if someone could explain to me: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>::push_back(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>&)`
- I understand that `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` is a matrix and
  that `push_back` adds an element at the end of the vector.
- I suspect that we're trying to read in the wrong type in
  `the_entries.push-back(row_as_vector)`.
- The original code took a `csv` file as input, containing `integers`
  and `strings`. Now we're reading in a `txt` file having the shape:

  `TEXT
     0; INT; INT; INT; INT; ...
     0; INT; INT; INT; INT; ...
     18 more lines of the above numbers and semicolons`

  In the above, we remove the first row in line `89`.
- Is it possible the code has to be changed much more to be able to
  read this `txt` file instead of the `csv` file?

**Rest of error message:**

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/vector:64:0,
                 from distanceMatrixToSageGraph.c:13:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:914:7: note: candidate: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::vector<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<int> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::vector<int>]
       push_back(const value_type& __x)
       ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:914:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const std::vector<int>&}’
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:932:7: note: candidate: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::vector<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<int> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::vector<int>]
       push_back(value_type&& __x)
       ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:932:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ to ‘std::vector<std::vector<int> >::value_type&& {aka std::vector<int>&&}’
```

**Whole code:**

```
// Convert distanceMatrix tables of protein interactions to SAGE graph.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void writeGraphInSageFormat(string name, std::vector<std::vector<int>> TheEdges) 
{
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Write out the edges in SAGE format.
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int edgeNumber = TheEdges.size();
    ofstream d1sageFile(name, ios::out);
    d1sageFile << "g = Graph([" << endl;

    for (int n = 0; n < edgeNumber; n++) {
        d1sageFile << "(" << TheEdges[n][0] + 1 << "," << TheEdges[n][1] + 1 << ")," << endl;
    }
    d1sageFile << "])" << endl;
    d1sageFile << "g.show()" << endl;
    d1sageFile.close();
    std::cout << "SAGE graph written into the file " << name << std::endl;
}

std::vector<std::vector<int>> ConvertEntriesMatrixToEdges(vector<vector<int>> the_entries, int threshold) 
{
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Construct the edge-vertex incidence matrix (d_1) from the distanceMatrix entries matrix:
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    std::vector<std::string> proteinNames;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> TheEdges;
    std::cout << "Registering only edges shorter than " << threshold << "." << std::endl;
    int thisDistance;
    for (int i = 0; i < the_entries.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < the_entries.size(); j++)
        {
            // we could use the_entries.size() instead of the_entries.at(i).size(), because this is a square matrix.
            thisDistance = the_entries.at(i).at(j);
            if (thisDistance < threshold) 
            {
                std::vector<int> CurrentEdge(2);
                CurrentEdge[0] = i;
                CurrentEdge[1] = j;
                TheEdges.push_back(CurrentEdge);
            };
        };
    };
    return TheEdges;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////
// Main Program: Extract edges from a distanceMatrix file.
///////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int argc, char** threshold_and_distanceMatrixfilename)
{
    if (argc < 2 || argc > 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: ./distanceMatrixToSageGraph.o <threshold> <distanceMatrix_file_calculated_fromDGEsingleCell_data>" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    string distanceMatrixfilename = threshold_and_distanceMatrixfilename[2];
    int threshold = std::stoi(threshold_and_distanceMatrixfilename[1]);
    std::ifstream distanceMatrixFile(distanceMatrixfilename);
    if (!distanceMatrixFile) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening distanceMatrix file: " << distanceMatrixfilename << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    string row;  //LINE 88
    std::getline(distanceMatrixFile, row); // discard the first row, which specifies the format of the file.
    vector<vector<int>> the_entries;

    while (std::getline(distanceMatrixFile, row))
    {
        std::stringstream row_as_stringstream(row);
        int i; i = 0;
        vector<string> row_as_vector;
        while (row_as_stringstream.good())
        {
            string substr;
            getline(row_as_stringstream, substr, ',');
            row_as_vector.push_back(substr);
        };
        the_entries.push_back(row_as_vector); //LINE 104
    };
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Now we assemble the entries to an edges matrix, and write it into a Sage file:
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> TheEdges = ConvertEntriesMatrixToEdges(the_entries, threshold);    
    char outputFilename[60]; strcpy(outputFilename, distanceMatrixfilename.c_str()); strcat(outputFilename, "AtThreshold"); string thrshld = std::to_string(threshold); strcat(outputFilename, thrshld.c_str()); strcat(outputFilename, ".txt");
    writeGraphInSageFormat(outputFilename, TheEdges);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `the_entries` is a `vector<vector<int>>` and you're trying to `push_back` `vector<string>`. That's a vector of `string`, not `int`. That's exactly like the error message says, perhaps it confused you that it called `std::string` `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>`.

Comment: you're trying to put `row_as_vector` (which is a vector of strings) into `the_entries` which is a vector of vector of integers. Hence your error.

Comment: @Blaze Exactly, I didn't know that `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>` was just  `std::string`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I suspect that we're trying to read in the wrong type in
>   the_entries.push-back(row_as_vector)

```
error: no matching function for call to 
‘std::vector<std::vector<int>>::push_back(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)’     
the_entries.push_back( row_as_vector );
```

**Yes**, your right about this. The error message says that you are trying to push back a *vector of strings* to a *vector of vector of integers*. They are entirely different types and hence not possible.

You probably want to either change the type of `the_entries` to

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> the_entries;
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or

convert the strings to integers using [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) while pushing back to the `std::vector<int> row_as_vector`.

```
std::vector<int> row_as_vector;
while(row_as_stringstream.good())
{
        // ......
        row_as_vector.push_back(std::stoi(substr));
        //                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
the_entries.push_back( row_as_vector );
```

---

> Is it possible the code has to be changed much more to be able to read
>   this `txt` file instead of the `csv` file?

If the contents of those two are same, you don't need to make much difference in your code. However, `;` should be [parsed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894886/parsing-a-comma-delimited-stdstring/1895584) before calling `std::stoi` to them. Because it may through *[invalid_argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol#Exceptions)* exception for the bad argument.

---

A few suggestions:

- Consider not to practice with `using namespace std;`. See this post
  for more:
  [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- When you pass the non-primitive types(i.e. `std::string`,
  `std::vector`.. etc) to the function, consider the case, if the
  parameters are read-only or not. If the data should be modified
  *pass-by-ref* and if read-only(no modification should have been made inside the function) pass them by *const-ref*. Read more:
  [How to pass objects to functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c)

Comment: Thank you very much. However, beforehand we used everything except the first row from the `csv` file. Now I assume we're only interested in the `integers`  from the `txt` file and not the semicolons. Don't we need to remove those first, or tell the code to ignore those?

Comment: @rlamesch Yes, you need to [parse the semicolens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894886/parsing-a-comma-delimited-stdstring/1895584) before converting them it to `int`.

Comment: The code compiles fine now, but there remain some problems. Firstly, it seems to have an issue with **`if (argc < 2 || argc > 2) `**. It throws the "*Usage: ./a.o <> <>*" error message. However, both are strict inequalities, so the code should be fine with 2 arguments. In the original code it read  **`if (argc < 2 || argc > 3) `**, which I changed it back to.

Comment: *" there remain some problems."*: looks like you have different problems now(other than asked above). Therefore, I would suggest asking for a new question regarding your new(other) problems.