# C++ separate string by selected commas

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I was reading the following question [Parsing a comma-delimited std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894886/parsing-a-comma-delimited-stdstring) on how to split a string by a comma (Someone gave me the link from my previous question) and one of the answers was:

```
stringstream ss( "1,1,1,1, or something else ,1,1,1,0" );
vector<string> result;

while( ss.good() )
{
    string substr;
    getline( ss, substr, ',' );
    result.push_back( substr );
}
```

But what if my string was like the following, and I wanted to separate values only by the bold commas and ignoring what appears inside `<>`?

<a,b>`,`<c,d>`,,`<d,l>`,`

**I want to get:**

```
<a,b>

<c,d>

"" //Empty string

<d,l>

""
```

1. **Given:**<a,b>,,<c,d> **It should return:** <a,b> and "" and <c,d>
2. **Given:**<a,b>,<c,d> **It should return:**<a,b> and <c,d>
3. **Given:**<a,b>, **It should return:**<a,b> and ""
4. **Given:**<a,b>,,,<c,d> **It should return:**<a,b> and "" and "" and <c,d>

**In other words,** my program should behave just like the given solution above separated by , (Supposing there is no other , except the bold ones)

---

**Here are some suggested solution and their problems:**

**Delete all bold commas:** This will result in treating the following 2 inputs the same way while they shouldn't

<a,b>,<c,d>

<a,b>,,<c,d>

**Replace all bold commas with some char and use the above algorithm:** I can't select some char to replace the commas with since any value could appear in the rest of my string

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219271/room-for-d4rk4ng31-and-daniel If you've time :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219303/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-c-separate-string-by-selected-commas).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Carlos' answer, apart from regex (take a look at my comment); you can implement the substitution like the following (Here, I actually build a new string):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string str;
    getline(std::cin,str);
    std::string str_builder;
    for (auto it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); it++) {
        static bool flag = false;
        if (*it == '<') {
            flag = true;
        }
        else if (*it == '>') {
            flag = false;
            str_builder += *it;
        }
        if (flag) {
            str_builder += *it;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are deleting the commas so how may I separate the values now?

Comment: @daniel, I ain't deleting the commas. I have simply eliminated the invalid ones. You are to implement a similar logic

Comment: But the following input "<a,b>,<c,d>" will result in "<a,b><c,d>" why I need this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not replace one set of commas with some known-to-not-clash character, then split it by the other commas, then reverse the replacement?

So replace the commas that are inside the <> with something, do the string split, replace again.

Comment: what are your suggestions for "some known-to-not-clash character" anything could appear in that string...

Comment: @daniel, take a look at my answer. I have improved and implemented this answer in my code :)

Comment: @daniel How about using a non-ASCII character, e.g. '\x01'`?

Comment: Sorry, I was away for a bit. What char doesn't clash is dependent on your use case. Sensible to follow the suggestion from @PaulSanders.

Comment: Does that work in C++11 how may I replace a char with non acsii one in string @PaulSanders

Comment: `MyString [index] = '\x01';` (or `MyString [index] = 1;`).

Comment: @PaulSanders         getline(vertices_stream, edge, '\x01' ); doesn't work

Comment: edge still has a value of empty string after this while it should be <a,b>... (The input is <a,b>)

Comment: @daniel Did you perform the substitution first?  Please show your code.

Comment: what substitution are you referring to @PaulSanders

Comment: Substituting commas you want to use as delimiters, as suggested above.  I'm going to drop out of this conversation.

Comment: @PaulSanders sure I did, actually there is nothing to replace in the following input <a,b> since there is no bold commas...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```cpp
vector<string> result;
string s = "<a,b>,,<c,d>"
int in_string = 0;
int latest_comma = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
    if(s[i] == '<'){
        result.push_back(s[i]);
        in_string = 1;
        latest_comma = 0;
    }
    else if(s[i] == '>'){
        result.push_back(s[i]);
        in_string = 0;
    }
    else if(!in_string && s[i] == ','){
        if(latest_comma == 1)
            result.push_back('\n');
        else
            latest_comma = 1;
    }            
    else
        result.push_back(s[i]);
}
```

Comment: I just checked, your answer is wrong plus it doesn't compile since result is a vector of string not chars

Comment: No, take a careful look. He is pushing the characters which lie between '<' and '>'

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 but that's not my question, I want to get the values between <> and another <> In other words this: <a>,,<b> should return a and "" and b

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible code that scans a string one char at a time and splits it on commas (`','`) unless they are *masked* between brackets (`'<'` and `'>'`).

Algo:

```
assume starting outside brackets
loop for each character:
   if not a comma, or if inside brackets
       store the character in the current item
       if a < bracket: note that we are inside brackets
       if a > bracket: note that we are outside brackets
   else (an unmasked comma)
       store the current item as a string into the resulting vector
       clear the current item
store the last item into the resulting vector
```

Only 10 lines and my rubber duck agreed that it should work...

C++ implementation: I will use a vector to handle the current item because it is easier to build it one character at a time

```
std::vector<std::string> parse(const std::string& str) {
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    bool masked = false;
    std::vector<char> current;        // stores chars of the current item
    for (const char c : str) {
        if (masked || (c != ',')) {
            current.push_back(c);
            switch (c) {
            case '<': masked = true; break;
            case '>': masked = false;
            }
        }
        else {            // unmasked comma: store item and prepare next
            current.push_back('\0');  // a terminating null for the vector data
            result.push_back(std::string(&current[0]));
            current.clear();
        }
    }
    // do not forget the last item...
    current.push_back('\0');
    result.push_back(std::string(&current[0]));
    return result;
}
```

I tested it with all your example strings and it gives the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Seems quite straight forward to me.

```
vector<string> customSplit(string s)
{
    vector<string> results;
    int level = 0;
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (char c : s)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case ',':
                if (level == 0)
                {
                    results.push_back(ss.str());
                    stringstream temp;
                    ss.swap(temp); // Clear ss for the new string.
                }
                else
                {
                    ss << c;
                }
                break;
            case '<':
                level += 2;
            case '>':
                level -= 1;
            default:
                ss << c;
        }
    }

    results.push_back(ss.str());
    return results;
}
```